# Certain letters overflowing their container - can anything be done?

Tags: css, overflow, typography

I have noticed the problem of certain letters overflowing their container on the left side, but I haven't seen anyone actually bringing up the problem.

I've tried between a few different font-families, but they all seem to have the same problem.

[image: J overflowing]
[image: T not overflowing (maybe a little, but very minor)]

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/3h5poynt/

**HTML (angular)**

```
<div class="personal-profile container-column">
<mat-card class="header">
    <section class="cover-section"></section>
    <section class="intro-section">
        <div class="intro-header">
            <div class="profile-photo-wrapper">
                <img src="/assets/img/profile-picture-placeholder.png" alt="" class="profile-photo" />
            </div>

            <div class="badges-container">
                <ul class="badges-list">
                    <li>
                        <img
                            src="/assets/badges/business-plans-180x180.png"
                            alt="Business plan"
                            matTooltip="Something"
                            matTooltipClass="badge-tooltip"
                            matTooltipPosition="above"
                        />
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="/assets/badges/calling-customers-180x180.png" alt="Calling customers" /></li>
                    <li><img src="/assets/badges/finance-180x180.png" alt="Finance" /></li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="/assets/badges/selling-to-customers-180x180.png" alt="Selling to customers" />
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="/assets/badges/social-media-180x180.png" alt="Social media" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info-container">
            <div class="personal-info">
                <div class="name-text">{{ profile ? profile.name : '' }}</div>
                <div class="description">{{ profile ? profile.personal_description : '' }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="additional-info"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</mat-card>
```

**SCSS**

```
@import '../../../variables';

.mat-card {
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    section {
        padding: 20px;
    }
}

.badge-tooltip {
    background: #3f51b5;
    color: white;
    font-family: $font-open-sans;
}

.personal-profile {
    margin-top: 50px;
    .header {
        min-height: 500px;
        width: 100%;

        .cover-section {
            background: url('/assets/img/coverpicture.png') center/cover;
            height: 225px;
        }

        .intro-section {
            .intro-header {
                size: auto;
                .profile-photo-wrapper {
                    position: relative;
                    margin-top: -87px;
                    display: inline-block;
                    .profile-photo {
                        width: 150px;
                        height: 150px;
                        border: 4px solid white;
                        border-radius: 10px;
                        box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1.5px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
                        background-color: #fff;
                    }
                }

                .badges-container {
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin-top: -87px;
                    .badges-list {
                        list-style: none;
                        li {
                            float: left;
                            padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
                            img {
                                width: 40px;
                                height: 40px;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            .info-container {
                padding-top: 15px;
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
                font-family: $font-open-sans;

                .personal-info,
                .additional-info {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                }

                .personal-info {
                    .name-text {
                        font-size: 1.3em;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Main SCSS**

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
@import '_variables.scss';

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: $font-open-sans;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e9ebee;
}

.container-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

.container-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Is there something very essential that I am missing, or is this something that has to be hacked?

Comment: Markup, please.

Comment: which font are you using? is there any css which could conflict? because: https://jsfiddle.net/t2dg5c1z/ it doesn't happen in this simple example... but then I also don't have this dot (triangle?) above the "J"

Comment: The point of showing code is to have a context to what containers you are talking about and to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Fair enough, i have added the code. Its just a problem I've witnessed dozens of times before, so I assumed it was a general thing.

Comment: I tried removing all font-styling now. And apparently that solved the issue. But it just seems strange that a font as popular as Open Sans should have this issue?

Comment: @JonasMohrPedersen But didn't you say in your post _"I've tried between a few different font-families, but they all seem to have the same problem."_? sounds like its not the font-family.... what other font styling did you remove to make it work?

Comment: @zgood Well, the only "styling" i have is changing the font size and the font-family. I tried setting it to lower font size and changing the font-family to roboto instead - but the problem persisted. So i assumed since i used 2 of the most popular font families that it was a general problem. But apparently after removing all custom font families it works. However it doesn't resolve the actual issue, since i want to be using Open Sans.

Comment: @Jonas Nah, we need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Olafant I will see what i can do, I just thought that giving a macro perspective could reveal something that I was not aware would produce the bug.

Comment: I think this has mainly to do how the typeface was built, in this example PT sans behaves similar: https://jsfiddle.net/7o0fz6sx/4/ More on Roboto here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roboto

Comment: I made a jsFiddle replicating the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/3h5poynt/

Comment: That's just kerning. If you want a solution, use some padding.

Comment: see also how AJ behaves: https://jsfiddle.net/h3o45vx7/

Comment: @MrLister The problem is i want it to align with other divs above and below it - so are you proposing that i add same amount of padding to everything I have in the left side?

Comment: @MrLister disregard above comment. Here is new: How will padding solve the problem? Then letters that are not overflowing will just be pushed further towards the right.

Answer (score 0):

Jonas,

Some fonts are "just like that".
You will find that (especially with some of the more amateurish free fonts available nowadays) that some fonts' descenders, ascenders, ornaments, etc just overlap the borders that we (programmers, readers) expect them to conform to.

If you really want to use a font like this in this specific context, then you have to program around the font's limitations.

In your fiddle, I merely added `padding-left` to the `name-text` style:

```
.name-text{
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background: red;
  padding-left:15px; /* voila! */
}
```

Give it a try in the fiddle.

If the left bearing is radically different on initial characters across the font, then you maybe able to set up various styles with padding that changes according to the substring value of the first character. Sounds like a bit of a living hell to program that, but if you really want it, there you go.

Or you could just pick a different font.